# I am trying to filter array with array of unique data using radio button using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[image]

I am trying to filter array of objects (courses) with array of unique data (tag) using radio button using react hooks. I am able to achieve the functionality but checking of radio button is not working. please help me to add checked inside <input type="radio" checked={ } />

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const courses = [
{ id: "1", course: "React Tutorial", tag: "react" },
{ id: "2", course: "Object-oriented programming (OOP)", tag: "oop" },
{ id: "3", course: "Java Programming", tag: "java" },
{ id: "4", course: "JavaScript Course", tag: "javascript" },
{ id: "5", course: "Spring Boot Tutorial", tag: "spring" },
{ id: "6", course: "Python Bootcamp", tag: "python" },
{ id: "7", course: "Spring Framework Course", tag: "spring" },
{ id: "8", course: "React with Redux", tag: "react" },
{ id: "9", course: "C#: Classes and OOP", tag: "oop" },
{ id: "10", course: "Java Masterclass", tag: "java" },
{ id: "11", course: "ES6 JavaScript Training", tag: "javascript" },
{ id: "12", course: "Learn Python Programming", tag: "python" },
];
const uniqueTags = [...new Set(courses.map((item: any) => item.tag))];

const App = () => {
const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState(courses);

const handleFilterItems = (tag: any) => {
 setFilterData(courses);
 const filteredItems = courses?.filter((item: any) => item.tag === tag);
 setFilterData(filteredItems);
};

return (
<>
  <input type="radio" onChange={() => setFilterData(courses)} /> All
  {uniqueTags.map((tag, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <input
        type="radio"
        key={index}
        // checked={tag}
        value={tag}
        onChange={() => handleFilterItems(tag)}
      />
      {tag}
    </div>
  ))}
  {filterData.map((course: any) => (
    <li key={course.id}>
      {course.id}-{course.course}-{course.tag}
    </li>
  ))}
</>
);
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code with Checkbox

```js
const courses = [
  { id: '1', course: 'React Tutorial', tag: 'react' },
  { id: '2', course: 'Object-oriented programming (OOP)', tag: 'oop' },
  { id: '3', course: 'Java Programming', tag: 'java' },
  { id: '4', course: 'JavaScript Course', tag: 'javascript' },
  { id: '5', course: 'Spring Boot Tutorial', tag: 'spring' },
  { id: '6', course: 'Python Bootcamp', tag: 'python' },
  { id: '7', course: 'Spring Framework Course', tag: 'spring' },
  { id: '8', course: 'React with Redux', tag: 'react' },
  { id: '9', course: 'C#: Classes and OOP', tag: 'oop' },
  { id: '10', course: 'Java Masterclass', tag: 'java' },
  { id: '11', course: 'ES6 JavaScript Training', tag: 'javascript' },
  { id: '12', course: 'Learn Python Programming', tag: 'python' },
];
const uniqueTags = [...new Set(courses.map(item => item.tag))];

const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState('all');
  const [filterData, setFilterData] = React.useState(courses);

  const handleFilterItems = tag => {
    setChecked(tag);
    if (tag !== 'all') {
      const filteredItems = courses.filter(item => item.tag === tag);
      setFilterData(filteredItems);
    } else {
      setFilterData(courses);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked === 'all'}
        onChange={() => handleFilterItems('all')}
      /> All
      {uniqueTags.map((tag, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked === tag}
            onChange={() => handleFilterItems(tag)}
          />
          {tag}
        </div>
      ))}
      {filterData.map((course) => (
        <li key={course.id}>
          {course.id}-{course.course}-{course.tag}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Code with Radio

```js
const courses = [
  { id: '1', course: 'React Tutorial', tag: 'react' },
  { id: '2', course: 'Object-oriented programming (OOP)', tag: 'oop' },
  { id: '3', course: 'Java Programming', tag: 'java' },
  { id: '4', course: 'JavaScript Course', tag: 'javascript' },
  { id: '5', course: 'Spring Boot Tutorial', tag: 'spring' },
  { id: '6', course: 'Python Bootcamp', tag: 'python' },
  { id: '7', course: 'Spring Framework Course', tag: 'spring' },
  { id: '8', course: 'React with Redux', tag: 'react' },
  { id: '9', course: 'C#: Classes and OOP', tag: 'oop' },
  { id: '10', course: 'Java Masterclass', tag: 'java' },
  { id: '11', course: 'ES6 JavaScript Training', tag: 'javascript' },
  { id: '12', course: 'Learn Python Programming', tag: 'python' },
];
const uniqueTags = [...new Set(courses.map(item => item.tag))];

const App = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState('all');
  const [filterData, setFilterData] = React.useState(courses);

  const handleFilterItems = tag => {
    setChecked(tag);
    if (tag !== 'all') {
      const filteredItems = courses.filter(item => item.tag === tag);
      setFilterData(filteredItems);
    } else {
      setFilterData(courses);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="radio"
        checked={checked === 'all'}
        onChange={() => handleFilterItems('all')}
      /> All
      {uniqueTags.map((tag, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            checked={checked === tag}
            onChange={() => handleFilterItems(tag)}
          />
          {tag}
        </div>
      ))}
      {filterData.map((course) => (
        <li key={course.id}>
          {course.id}-{course.course}-{course.tag}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank a lot Jay Vaghasiya. Excellent :-) This works with input type radio. How can I achieve the functionality if input type="checkbox" instead of type="radio". Can you please add new code (by using above example but with input type checkbox now) with type checkbox and checked inside input, so that I can do comparison between input types radio and checkbox

Comment: @TruptiGaonkar code is updated, please do check

Comment: 99% will not change, only change is type, other code will be same

Comment: @TruptiGaonkar mostly for single select we use radio, checkbox is for multi select. so in my opinion radio is most suitable in your case because of single select.

Comment: @TruptiGaonkar also please do upvote and mark as answer if this is helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the selected tag as a `state`.
I have modified your code like this.

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";

const courses = [
  { id: "1", course: "React Tutorial", tag: "react" },
  { id: "2", course: "Object-oriented programming (OOP)", tag: "oop" },
  { id: "3", course: "Java Programming", tag: "java" },
  { id: "4", course: "JavaScript Course", tag: "javascript" },
  { id: "5", course: "Spring Boot Tutorial", tag: "spring" },
  { id: "6", course: "Python Bootcamp", tag: "python" },
  { id: "7", course: "Spring Framework Course", tag: "spring" },
  { id: "8", course: "React with Redux", tag: "react" },
  { id: "9", course: "C#: Classes and OOP", tag: "oop" },
  { id: "10", course: "Java Masterclass", tag: "java" },
  { id: "11", course: "ES6 JavaScript Training", tag: "javascript" },
  { id: "12", course: "Learn Python Programming", tag: "python" }
];
const uniqueTags = [...new Set(courses.map((item) => item.tag))];

const App = () => {
  const [selectedTag, setSelectedTag] = useState("");

  const handleFilterItems = (tag) => {
    setSelectedTag(tag);
  };

  const filterData = useMemo(
    () =>
      selectedTag
        ? courses?.filter((item) => item.tag === selectedTag)
        : courses,
    [selectedTag]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="radio"
        checked={selectedTag === ""}
        onChange={() => handleFilterItems("")}
      />{" "}
      All
      {uniqueTags.map((tag, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            key={index}
            checked={tag === selectedTag}
            value={tag}
            onChange={() => handleFilterItems(tag)}
          />
          {tag}
        </div>
      ))}
      {filterData.map((course) => (
        <li key={course.id}>
          {course.id}-{course.course}-{course.tag}
        </li>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

As you can see, selected tag value should be stored as a `state` and `filterData` should be calculated via `selectedTag`.
You can check on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sammet-1490o5?file=/src/App.js).